# com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 Authentication required in Jenkins

Tags: email, jenkins, smtp, jenkins-mailer-plugin

I've turned on less secured apps on google.
Checked use SMTP Authentication in Jenkins.

Tried using AWS Simple email service too.
But still, Authentication required error is showing up

Error logs using Google SMTP

```
ERROR: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
530 5.5.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError x9sm20383081pje.27 - gsmtp

com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
530 5.5.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError x9sm20383081pje.27 - gsmtp

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2057)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1580)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1097)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:195)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at hudson.tasks.MailSender.run(MailSender.java:130)
    at hudson.tasks.Mailer.perform(Mailer.java:175)
    at hudson.tasks.Mailer.perform(Mailer.java:138)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:741)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1840)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Error logs using using AWS Simple Email Service

```
ERROR: 530 Authentication required

com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 Authentication required

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2057)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1580)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1097)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:195)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at hudson.tasks.MailSender.run(MailSender.java:130)
    at hudson.tasks.Mailer.perform(Mailer.java:175)
    at hudson.tasks.Mailer.perform(Mailer.java:138)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:741)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1840)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: what credentials are you using for aws ses ? this should be from ses console --> SMTP settings

Comment: Yes, the credentials from SMPT Settings only being used for that

Comment: okay, can you try to use the base64 encoded access and secret key and try again ?  use echo 'access' | base64 and echo 'secret' | base64 and use them instead.